# Polynomial between $0$ and $1$ that produces largest integral

Tags: polynomials, optimization

Question:

> Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Find the polynomial $p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_ix^i$  that satisfies
>
> $p(1) = 1$ (and $p(0)=0$ since we already have $a_0=0$)
>
> $p(x) \in [0,1]$ for all $x\in [0,1]$
>
> and (under these restrictions) maximizes the integral $\int_0^1 p(x)dx$.

Here's what I've tried:

I try to solve it for $n=2$. Then $a_2=1-a_1$, $a_1\geq 0$ and $a_1\leq \frac{1-x^2}{x-x^2} (=: f(x))$ for $x\in[0,1]$. I must maximize $\frac{5a_1-2}{6}$ in other words make $a_1$ as large as possible. The function $f(x)$ gives the bound $a_1\leq 2$, so I get $p(x) = -x^2+2x$

My thougts on the general problem: Maybe $a_1 = p'(0)$ should be as large as possible. I (accidentally) tried $p'(1)=1$ (I was going for $p'(1)=0$, but this gives a worse solution). Using these, I get for $n=3$ that, $a_1(x^3-2x^2+x)\leq x^3-2x^2+1$ and that $a_1=5$ and $p(x)=4x^3-8x^2+5x$. This is a rather good solution (it gives area $0.8331$) but it's arbitrary to set the value of $p'(1)$ (I just tried it because at first I thought that setting $p'(1)=0$ would be good, but, as seen, a better solution can be achieved by having the peak before $1$. And maybe for general $n$ to have all the peaks inside $[0,1]$ to make $p$ stay as close to $1$ as possible.)

Comment: We can obtain that $4x^3-8x^2+5x$ is the best cubic by looking for local maxima - if we carefully examine polynomials of the form $p_t(x)=p(x)+tx(1-x)(x-a)$, we can find that we can, by choosing some $t$ near $0$, increase the integral of any $p$ such that $p(\frac{1}2)<1$ while still having $p_t(x)$ satisfy the desired conditions. Thus $p(\frac{1}2)=1$ (and hence $p'(\frac{1}2)=0$) for the optimal polynomial, leading us immediately to $4x^3-8x^2+5x$.

Comment: In fact, the same reasoning leads us to find that $p(\frac{1}2)=1$ for the best degree four polynomial as well. Then it's not so hard to figure out that $p'(1)=0$ by considering translating $p$ by $x^2(1-x)(x-\frac{1}2)$ in place of $x(1-x)(x-a)$. So, the best quartic is $$-4x^4+12x^3-13x^2+6x$$
(And, I think, more generally, translating with $x(1-x)^2(x-a_1)^2(x-a_2)^2\ldots$ one may show that the best degree $2n-1$ polynomial has $n$ solutions to $p(1)=1$, all in $(0,1]$)

Comment: @Meelo Thanks. That seems like a nice trick, but I'm not understanding it fully. What's $a$? How do we know that we can add the $t$-part (with the sign of t that increases the integral) if $p(c)=1$ for some other point than $c=\frac{1}{2}$? Is this controlled with the $a$? Sorry, I'm not getting it...

Comment: @Meelo OK, now I got it. $a\in (0,1)$ is the point where $p(a)=1$. And the integral of the additional part is zero when $a=\frac{1}{2}$, right?

Comment: Yes, exaclty; I'm expanding my comments into an answer at the moment. I've not found a closed form, but I can prove that $p'(1)=0$ for all even degree polynomials and that $p(x)-1$ has $n$ roots for any polynomial of degree $2n+1$ or $2n+2$ - which transforms this into an easier problem that I believe is essentially irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comments, we can show that any optimal polynomial of degree $2n+1$ has the form
$$1-p(x)=\alpha(1-x)(x-r_1)^2(x-r_2)^2\ldots(x-r_n)^2$$
and those of degree $2n+2$ have the form
$$1-p(x)=\alpha(1-x)^2(x-r_1)^2(x-r_2)^2\ldots(x-r_n)^2$$
where, in either case, $\alpha=\frac{1}{r_1^2r_2^2\ldots r_n^2}$. This is still difficult to solve, however, it at least reduces the problem to optimizing a rational function subject to constraints of the form $0\leq r_i \leq 1$ - which will at least have an algebraic solution and is amenable to numerical methods.

First, we need to show that for any $p(x)$ there is some $q(x)$ such that $\int_{0}^1q(x)\,dx\geq \int_{0}^1 p(x)\,dx$ and $q(x)>0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$. To do this, we handle the case where there is some $c\in(0,1)$ such that $p(c)=0$. Letting $m\in(0,c)$ be such that $p(m)$ is maximized in $(0,c)$, we can define the following, which are all "segments" of $p$ translated and scaled:
$$p_1(x)=\frac{p(mx)}{p(m)}$$
$$p_2(x)=\frac{p(c-(c-m)x)}{p(m)}$$
$$p_3(x)=p(c+(1-c)x)$$
and note that $$\int_{0}^1p(x)\,dx = m\cdot\left[p(m)\int_{0}^1p_1(x)\,dx\right]+ (c-m)\cdot\left[p(m)\int_{0}^1p_2(x)\,dx\right]+(1-c)\cdot \left[\int_{0}^1 p_3(x)\,dx\right]$$ which, since $m+(c-m)+(1-c)=1$, we may regard as a weighted average, meaning one of the bracketed terms is at least $\int_{0}^1p(x)\,dx$. Thus, one of $p_1,p_2,p_3$ has at least the same integral as $p$, but all have less roots in $(0,1)$ - hence, iterating this process, we may eventually choose some section of $p$ which has a greater integral when scaled to the interval $[0,1]$, but which has no roots in $(0,1)$. Thus, from here on, we may (and will) assume that all polynomials $p$ have no roots in $(0,1)$.

Next, we will prove that any suitable polynomial of degree $2n+1$ or $2n+2$ whose integral is at a local maximum must have that $p(x)-1$ has $n$ roots in $(0,1)$. To do this, consider arbitrary $p(x)$ chosen to fit the desired conditions. Suppose that $p(x)-1$ has $k$ roots in $(0,1)$. Given that every root is a double root (at least) and that there is an additional root at $x=1$, we know that $2k+1$ is less than the degree of the polynomial, so therefore $k\leq n$. We then show that the integral of $p$ may be increased if $k<n$.

To do this, label the roots to $p(x)-1$ as $r_1,\ldots,r_k$. First, let us define the polynomial
$$q(x)=x(1-x)^2(x-r_1)^2(x-r_2)^2\ldots(x-r_k)^2$$
which has degree $2k+3\leq 2n+1$. Note that it is everywhere non-negative, and hence $Q=\int_{0}^{1}q(x)\,dx$ is positive. Let $Q'$ be the minimum of $Q$ and $q'(0)$ (both of which are positive) and define
$$s(x)=q(x)-Q'x(1-x)$$
which must have that $\int_{0}^1s(x)\,dx> \frac{5}6Q>0$ since $\int_{0}^1x(1-x)\,dx =\frac{1}6$. However, it *also* satisfies that $s(r_i)<0$ and that $s(x)\geq 0$ in some neighborhood of $0$ and that $s(x)\leq 0$ in some neighborhood of $1$. This is helpful because if we define the map $f:(0,1)\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ to be
$$f(x)=\max\{c:0\leq p(x)+cs(x)\leq 1\}$$
we can find that it is continuous (in the extended reals), clearly always greater than $0$, and can be continuously extended to $[0,1]$ (while still being everywhere positive). Thus, we may conclude that there is some $C$ such that $f(x)\geq C$ for all $x$, meaning that $p(x)+Cs(x)$ still satisfies the given constraints, but has a greater integral - meaning $p(x)$ cannot have been a maximum. Thus, any polynomial attaining the maximum integral has that $p(x)-1$ has $n$ distinct roots in $(0,1)$.

We may repeat the same process, letting $q(x)=x(1-x)(x-r_1)^2\ldots(x-r_k)^2$ and $Q'$ chosen to be positive and such that $Q'\leq q'(0)$, $Q'\leq \int_{0}^{1}q(x)\,dx$, and $Q'<-q'(1)$. Doing this will yield that, defining $s$ like before, $s'(1)<0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x)=\frac{f'(1)}{-s'(1)}$ which is positive so long as $f'(1)>0$, meaning that if $f'(1)>0$, we may increase the function as before, and therefore we conclude that $f'(1)=0$ in that case. These statements suffice to show that the desired $p$ are of the above form.

For the first few degrees, here are the optimal polynomials (according to Mathematica)
$$x$$
$$-x^2+2x$$
$$4x^3-8x^2+5x$$
$$-\frac{25}4x^4+\frac{35}2x^3-\frac{69}4x^2 + 7x$$
$$25x^5-75x^4+85x^3-45x^2+11x$$
$$- 49 x^6+182x^5-267x^4+196x^3-75x^2+14x $$
$$196x^7-784x^6+1281x^5-1099x^4+529x^3-141x^2+19x$$

Comment: Now, the real question is why all the coefficients are rational. I didn't expect that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's certainly surprising to get (integral) rational coefs. But is there something wrong with the $7$th order one? It doesn't look right when I graph it.

Comment: @ploosu2 Fixed it (I had $x^2$ where I wanted $x^3$).

Comment: @ploosu2 More strangely still, it seems that the best polynomial of degree $2n+1$ has integral $1-\frac{1}{n^2+3n+2}$ and the best polynomial of degree $2n+2$ has integral $1-\frac{1}{n^2+4n+3}$. It holds through degree $14$. I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: For $n=6$, $p(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{r_1^2r_2^2}(1-x)^2(x-r_1)^2(x-r_2)^2$ for $r_1 = \frac{3}{7}-\frac{\sqrt2}{7}$ and $r_2 = \frac{3}{7}+\frac{\sqrt2}{7}$. So we should have $\int_0^1 x(1-x)(x-\frac{3}{7}+\frac{\sqrt2}{7})(x-\frac{3}{7}-\frac{\sqrt2}{7})dx$ to be zero so we can't do the "tiny addition trick" to increase the integral. But, in fact the integral is $\frac{1}{420} \neq 0$. What's wrong here?

Comment: Same problem with $n=4$ and $n=7$ (For $n=7$ the integral is $1/840$). For $n=5$ the integral is zero.

Comment: @ploosu2 If I understand you correctly, you seem to talking about the converse of what I prove (which is, as you show, false). Every local maximum is a function of that form, but not every function of that form is a local maximum. I suspect one can refine my result by trying out the same trick with other polynomials, like your integrand.

Comment: No, actually the sixth order one on your list has peaks at those $r_1$ and $r_2$, that is:
$$p(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{(\frac{3}{7}-\frac{\sqrt2}{7})^2(\frac{3}{7}+\frac{\sqrt2}{7})^2} (1-x)^2 (x-\frac{3}{7}+\frac{\sqrt2}{7})^2(x-\frac{3}{7}-\frac{\sqrt2}{7})^2 $$
$$= -49 x^6+182x^5-267x^4+196x^3-75x^2+14x$$

Comment: @ploosu2 Okay, I think I understand you - that, at a maximum, the integral $\int_0^1 q(x) dx$ ought to be zero for any suitable $q$. At least with the polynomial $x(1-x)(x-\frac{3}7+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{7})(x-\frac{3}7-\frac{\sqrt{2}}7)$ we have a steep negative slope near $1$, which, when added to $p(x)$, which has $p'(0)=0$ will make $(p+Cs)'(1)<0$, forcing it above $1$ a little below $x=1$ (unless we chose $Q'$ to be large, presumably large enough to cancel out the $\frac{1}{420}$ integral). The non-zero integral for $n=7$ still concerns me - I can't (yet?) see why that would be.